# REACT - not working npm while installing it

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, reactjs, npm

Did all the command on command line
from installing the npm globally `npm install -g create-react-app`  along with following codes:

`npx create-react-app <myprojectname>`
and also cleared the npm cache but it always get stuck on the line in the image showing the following error. Along with the error:

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                     npm update check failed                      │
│               Try running with sudo or get access                │
│               to the local update config store via               │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) C:\Users\Smart Sites\.config │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

along with `65 packages are looking for funding`
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJVVp.png

Comment: if you have yarn, try `yarn create-react-app <myprojectname>`

Comment: Try opening the command prompt in administrative mode

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá I tried it with yarn, it didn't work. [Please see the link.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p4wzUESPRLvoPr4wzFpWC-Y2xzdbTDWS/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi it got stuck here from past 45 mins.
see the following [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bASTC4fYZUsWU3ajnxOHz3mcMpTfk-hE/view)

Comment: @DivijDevkota , it did not create the project , did you check ? Also any error ?

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi no it did not create the project and there was no error too.
Just the message as on the image attached.

Comment: @DivijDevkota, I would suggest to raise the issue on github .

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi i have already raised this issue on github but i have not got any response from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i found form the getting started page of create react app.

If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via

```
  npm install -g create-react-app,
```

we recommend you uninstall the package using

```
 npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

to ensure that npx always uses the latest version.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

But always ensure that you have an existing folder before using npx.

Comment: already this process have been done, i am working in windows can you suggest me any other option ??